# How to create an object of another class in Flask only once

Tags: python, flask

I am using  flask for serving a post request. I have the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from another_file import Another_Class_Somewhere_Else

app = Flask(__name__)
od = ""

@app.route("/call_my_func", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello(): 
    res = od.some_func()
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global od
    my_param = "dummy_string"
    od = Another_Class_Somewhere_Else(my_param)
    app.run(debug=True, host='10.0.10.15')
```

As you can see above, my objective is to create an object of another class only once. Then use this object to run a method of the another class every time we get a post request?

What is wrong with the method above because it doesn't seem to create the object once.

Comment: You want to use your class per application or per request?

Comment: How do you know that there more than one object?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I would like to create an object of the class only once. Once per application. Then for every reqyest it is ok to use the same object

Comment: @vZ10 I get a warning right now that od is being used before it is initialized or something like that.

Comment: If you want help, you need to be more specific than "or something like that". What, *exactly*, is the error message?

Comment: Maybe try ```global od = ""``` and remove the ```global od``` from the main loop.

Comment: @ISOmetric yes thanks, doing what you suggested solves the problem and removes the unnecesary warning.